# The most RESTful file sending Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, file, rest, upload

In my app I need feature which uploads (or sends to user some file). For now my controller is as follows: (only for upload)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload")
public class UploadController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void uploadFile(@RequestParam(value = "name") final String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response){
        try {
            if(!file.isEmpty()){
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + ".mp3")));
                outputStream.write(bytes);
                outputStream.close();
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

So it is actually equal to the tutorial's controller at spring.io page. (thought it is just pre-version, made for tests - I know that logic should be moved to @Service's etc.)

But my question is - Because I see that it is not so RESTful approach, because to upload this file (at least for browser-client) I have to make form which posts name and file to /upload url - I would like to know how can I do it more RESTful?

I heard that apache commons has some userful upload library, but don't know if it will be userful here.

any suggestions?

By The Way:
Do you have any advices for me how to handle with files through RESTful web services? What about sending multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

The way we have used to design a restful service for uploading a file is the following: You can use a name like "files" to describe your file resources collection or something more specific e.g. "videos" if it does not refer to files in general. Posting to /files will then add a file to that collection, like what a REST post is supposed to do. The file can be passed in the post body encoded in base64 form. Performing a GET in /files/{id} will retrieve the file, again in base64 string form. Our requests and responses are in JSON but you can use whatever you prefer to include the string.

Any website that wants to call your rest service, will have to contain a form like you said, and the upload method that receives the file will convert it from bytes[] to a base64 encoded string and then call the restful service. Any android client could get a file from the phone, convert it to base64 string and use that service too to send it etc.

But if you only want to use that functionality from your own website, the above proposal is a bit too much. In that case I suggest you leave it as is, since the upload part where the file is loaded from a form cannot be avoided anyway, and there is no need to introduce intermediate levels of services just for being RESTful by the book. From experience, I often find various operations that are hard to map to RESTful operations (e.g. complex actions or management operations) and it is often better to have a clean and easy design than being extreme about following conventions

Comment: so you mean to send the base64 encoded file in the BODY of the request, not as a parameter (like I do now)? And next thing is: file sending should be made by using form with file-type-input or posted using javascript? (I mean: we have form, which is handled by self-made javascript function in which I post file to the url) Which approach is more useful? (p.s. I am going to have multiple clients like android, desktop and browser app)

Comment: Yes, the approach with file encoded as a base64 string would be sending it at the body. However the way you do it now using MultipartFile is the only way I know to upload the file using a form. So this cannot be avoided. You can only add the method I propose  additionally to yours, so that it can be called via other clients (e.g android) that do not use a form upload. The bottom line is that if you need to support a form-based upload, you cannot avoid the multipartfile approach, and if that approach can work for all type of clients, adding another method just to be Restful may not worth it.

Comment: I think i understood everything quite well, but have another question :) If some client encode some file to base64, how can I recieve this file from request body in my Spring controller?  I mean how to create java object from request base64 encoded body in controller? @Marios

Comment: the base64 encoded file is just a string, so you can include it in the request body as a plain java "String" object. From String you can convert it again to bytes like this: byte[] file = java.util.Base64.Base64.getDecoder().decode(mystring); (note that Base64 support was added in java 8. for earlier versions you need third party lib like apache commons). Likewise you can convert a file to base64 string using getEncoder().encodeToString method)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this class (and there are plenty of associated tutorials out there).

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html

Comment: I rather mean, how to be more restful than which class to use

Comment: yep I got that, but I wonder if it is restful to let my client post my service using FORM rather than posting using for example jQuery and recieve response information. When someone posts using form, cant recieve the info (which means he doesnt get i.e response code)